# SQL delete foreign key

Tags: php, sql, sql-delete

```
    +--------+--------+
    |A_id    |A_desc  |
    +--------+--------+

    table B:
    +--------+--------+
    |B_id    |B_desc  |
    +--------+--------+

    table c:
    +--------+--------+
    |A_id    |B_id    |
    +--------+--------+
```

I want to delete 1 row in c table and 1 row in b table without deleting table a by getting value of "B_id", anyone can solve this problem?

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? Why does table 'A' is getting modified? Are there any triggers?

Comment: Table A does not depend on any of the other tables; so, unless there is some trigger set by your team, you should be able to delete from table B and C with no issue.

Answer (score 1):

you can only do that with triggers / writhing some other code to do that for you.

Note that even if you do use triggers / code, you might get an exception since other records in C can point to table B.

What you can do is run something like:

```
delete from B where B_id not in (select B_id from C)
```

after you run the delete